# CLLocationManager not getting current location all the times

Tags: ios7, cllocationmanager

In my iOS 7 app, I have to get current location every time the app launches. I have kept the

following code.

```
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

locationManager.delegate = self;

locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers;

[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

I have Added CLLocationManagerDelegate in .h  I am getting current location in this delegate

method but not all the times.

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
```

What could be the problem? Why some times this delegate method was not called? Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: maybe "`didUpdateLocations:`" only fires when the device moves and new location data becomes available?  Try changing the simulator location via "`Simulator -> Debug -> Location`" while your app is running.

Comment: In what method is `startUpdatingLocation` called? Are you sure that it is being executed every time you believe it is? Are you checking that `locationManager` is not nil after calling `[[CLLocationManager alloc] init]`?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann Hi mike, i have changed the simulator->debug-location. I am getting current location but not every time. Thank you

Comment: @bneely Hi friend, i am calling startUpdatingLocaiton in AppDelegate's  didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method.

Comment: @RajugoudBingi In your testing, are you relaunching the app every time from Xcode or a device? Note that if it restores from a background state, `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` is not called again. You might instead want to use a different `UIApplicationDelegate` method such as `applicationDidBecomeActive:`.